# EndpointConnectionError: Could not connect to the endpoint URL: "https://secretsmanager.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/"

Tags: amazon-web-services

I configured alternating passwords in the secrets manager. But whenever i rotate the secret, I get the following error from the (automatically created) lambda function:

```
EndpointConnectionError: Could not connect to the endpoint URL: "https://secretsmanager.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/"
```

What do i have to configure here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message indicates that the lambda function is unable to talk to the secrets manager endpoint.

Since you've configured the lambda function to run in a VPC (otherwise you wouldn't see this error), this means that the route table associated with the VPC does have a route to an internet gateway nor to a NAT gateway.

If your lambda function only requires connectivity to AWS services, then the best solution is to provision VPC endpoints for every service you require (in this case, secrets manager).

If your lambda function requires general internet connectivity (so not only AWS endpoints), then you should configure the VPC for internet access.